# Iterate through a list, compare values

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, for-loop

`(1 ≤ N ≤ 1e+5)`
I have to find how many cases in this condition:
`i < j and array[i] > array[j]`
here I have tried:

```
k = int(input())
n = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
h=0
i=0
j=0
for j in range(k-1):
    for i in range(j+1,k):
        if n[j]>n[i]:
            h+=1
print(h)
```

but it gives time limit. is there better way to iterate it.
Test case 1:

```
10
7 6 2 4 1 5 10 3 9 8
```

Comment: I used reduce but it has same effect and timelimit occured ```k = int(input())
n = list(map(int, input().split()))
h=0
for i in range(k):
    h+=len(list(filter(lambda x:n[i]>x,n[i:])))
    #print(list(filter(lambda x:n[i]>x,n[i:])))
print(h)```

Comment: Don't put code like that in a comment, edit your question and add it as formatted text. In any case, why are you using `list(reduce(...))`?

Comment: Also, when you make a stack overflow question, please spare us the `input()` nonsense. Just give us example data.